Errors when running python code from "maj + enter" in VSCODE but file runs correctly from command line "python vote.py"
I have this python code that comes from here https://github.com/joelgrus/data-science-from-scratch/blob/master/scratch/k_nearest_neighbors.py
from typing import List
from collections import Counter

def majority_vote(labels: List[str]) -> str:
    """Assumes that labels are ordered from nearest to farthest."""    
    vote_counts = Counter(labels)
    winner, winner_count = vote_counts.most_common(1)[0]
    count = [count for count in vote_counts.values()
              if count == winner_count]
    num_winners = len(count)
    if num_winners == 1: 
        return winner
    else:
        return majority_vote(labels[:-1])
       
# Tie, so look at first 4, then 'b'
assert majority_vote(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']) == 'b'

When I select it all in Visual Studio Code and press MAJ + ENTER, I get the following error :
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> from typing import List
>>> from collections import Counter
>>>
>>> def majority_vote(labels: List[str]) -> str:
...     """Assumes that labels are ordered from nearest to farthest."""    
...     vote_counts = Counter(labels)
...     winner, winner_count = vote_counts.most_common(1)[0]
...     count = [count for count in vote_counts.values()
...               if count == winner_count]
...     num_winners = len(count)
...     if num_winners == 1: 
...         return winner
...     else:
...         return majority_vote(labels[:-1])
...
... # Tie, so look at first 4, then 'b'
... assert majority_vote(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']) == 'b'
  File "<stdin>", line 14
    assert majority_vote(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a']) == 'b'
    ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But if I run it from the command line with python vote.py it runs with no errors.
Can you help me understand this behaviour please?
Python version : Python 3.12.4 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Jun 18 2024, 15:03:56) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Thanks !
I tried to copy-paste the whole file from Joel Grus' GitHub repository and run it in Visual Studio Code but I get the same error as when I manually entered everything.

Duplicates: Syntax error when defining a function on the Python command line, Why am I getting an invalid syntax error in Python REPL right after IF statement?.
